# Can't connect client to server using static IP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

Just setting up a preliminary test to get some basic networking going across LAN and I'm having a problem. I wrote a script that functions as either a server or client based on a `bool` setting ( `host = true/false` ). I've built the server app and put it on one system with a static IP of `192.168.1.160`. I'm running my client in Unity Editor and I'm getting the error:

> 'ClientDisconnected due to error: Timeout UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity:UNetStaticUpdate()'

What am I doing wrong in my script? Many thanks for looking at this!

```
public class NetworkController : NetworkManager {

    public static NetworkController netCtrl = null; // create singleton
    public bool host = false;
    private int hostPort = 7777;
    private string hostIP = "192.168.1.160";
    private bool useNat = true;
    private string networkConnections;
    private bool serverLaunched;
    private bool clientLaunched;
    private int maxPlayers = 32;

    private void Awake()
    {
        InitNetworkController();
    }

    void InitNetworkController()
    {
        if (netCtrl == null)
            netCtrl = this;
        else if (netCtrl != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        if (host && !Network.isServer)
        {
            // setup server
            LaunchServer();
        }

        if (!host && !Network.isClient) 
        {
            // setup client
            LaunchClient();
        }
    }

    void LaunchServer()
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting Server");
        Network.InitializeServer(32, hostPort, useNat);
    }

    void LaunchClient()
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting Client");
        Network.Connect(hostIP, hostPort);
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (Network.isServer)
        {
            GUILayout.Label("Running as a server.");
            InvokeRepeating("CheckForConnections", 1f, 1f);
            GUILayout.Label("There are " + networkConnections + " client(s) connected");

        }   
        else if (Network.isClient)
        {
            GUILayout.Label("Running as a client.");
        }
        else
        {
            GUILayout.Label("We have a problem!");
        }   
    }

    void CheckForConnections()
    {
        networkConnections = NetworkServer.connections.Count.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your server ? IP beginning with 192 is a local IP. If your server isn't in your client LAN, you need to use the public IP. You may also need to do some port forwarding server side to enable access on port 7777 from outside.

Comment: my server and clients are both local, running on a closed network